# Boubble sorting with arrays with C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, recursion

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  void sorting(){

    int a[4];
  a[0]=1; 
  a[1]=6;
  a[2]=15; 
  a[3]=3;
  a[4]=19; 
  int size = 4; 

    int t =1; 
  if (size ==0) return; // ie if you reach to the end stop


  int i; 
  for (i=0;i<size-1;i++){ 

    if(a[i+1] >a[i]) { //if the +1 element is bigger than before it do the swap

         int j;
         j= a[i+1]; 
        a[i+1]=a[i]; //swap
         a[i] = j;    //swap 

       }
  }
    sorting(*a,size - 1);//recursion 

void print_int() {
  int i; // Loop counter 

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
  }}

}
```

It compiles ok but when I try to run the file nothing appears? My intentions were to create an array sort them then display them.

Also, the code where the recursion happened "sorting(*a,size - 1);//"
if I tried to replace *a with a[] an error will happen. Why is that?
the error is "error expected expression before ']' token"!

thank you.

Comment: Run the file?  Are you compiling and executing it?

Comment: Too many problems here: the out-of-bounds a[4], sub-function without parameters which are never called... please read some book about C syntax first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has to many problems. Here is a working Array sort:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubble_sort(int *array, int length){
    int i,j, k, temp;

    for (i = 0 ; i < length-1; i++){
        for (k = 0 ; k < length-i-1; k++){
          if (array[k] > array[k+1]){
            temp = array[k];
            array[k]   = array[k+1];
            array[k+1] = temp;
          }
        }
    }

    printf("The sorted Array List:\n\n");

    for ( j = 0 ; j < length ; j++ ){
        printf("%d  ", array[j]);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int array[] = {1,6,15,3,19};
    int length = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];

    bubble_sort(array, length);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

You should read about functions declarations and definitions.

About arrays you should know that if you declare:

```
int array[4];
```

Your working array is from **0** to **3** and not from **0** to **4**.
Take a look at the following:

```
int main(void){
    int array[] = {1,6,15,3,19};
    int size = 5;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have **size=5** and not **size=4**- like you tried. You should be careful about number of Array elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a[4];
```

But you access `a[4]=19;` index `4` that is out of bound. You can access highest index `3`.

I think function `void sorting()` should be defined outside `main` .Nested functions are GNU extensions in GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from all the problems spotted by others, you must *repeatedly* execute the `for` loop until no more exchanges are made, which is the standad way of bubbling. As you use recursion, it is of course nonsense to declare the array to be sorted (and its size) *inside* the function called recursively.